# how do we join in XPATH using version 1.0?

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

I'm trying to get the lN and the names of a person and the price of a car rental which is > 300

***below is my XML example:***

```
<rent number="101111">
    <car>
        <startDate>2018-02-08</startDate>
        <endDate>2018-03-05</endDate>
        <Location>Toranto</Location>
        <carType>BMW</carType>
        <transmissionType>Automatic</transmissionType>
    </car>
    <person>
        <licenseNumber> 02389749372 </licenseNumber>
        <name>Alexa Steve</name>
        <dob>1999-03-01</dob>
        <phone>
            <type>Home</type>
            <number>44 010 1111 4567</number>
        </phone>
        <email> Alexa@steve.ca</email>
    </person>
    <price>
        <Rate>100.50</Rate>
    </price>
</rent>



<rent number="103311">
    <car>
        <startDate>2018-07-01</startDate>
        <endDate>2018-09-05</endDate>
        <Location>ottawa</Location>
        <carType>audi 8</carType>
        <transmissionType>Automatic</transmissionType>
    </vehicle>
    <person>
        <licenseNumber> 033329372 </licenseNumber>
        <name>mike lornco</name>
        <dob>1960-03-03</dob>
        <phone>
            <type>Home</type>
            <number>44 010 1111 3333</number>
        </phone>
        <email> mikelornokorenco@gmail.com</email>
    </person>
    <price>
        <Rate>300.50</Rate>
    </price>
</rent>
```

***what I am trying to do is to get the driving licence and age of a person who has a car rental which is >= 300***

the separate query which works:

```
//price[Rate >= 300]
```

```
//person/name/licenseNumber
```

```
//person/name
```

```
//car/carType
```

Comment: With XPath questions, please say which version of XPath.

Comment: the version of xpath is 1.0 @MichaelKay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These expressions should work (result is a formatted string containing the required information) :

Xpath 1.0 :

```
concat(normalize-space(//Rate[.>=300]/preceding::licenseNumber[1]),"|",//Rate[.>=300]/preceding::name[1],"|",2020-substring(//Rate[.>=300]/preceding::dob[1],1,4))
```

Xpath 2.0 :

```
concat(replace(string-join(//Rate[.>=300]/preceding::person[1]/*[position()<3],"|"),"\W(\d+)\W(|.+)","$1$2"),"|",year-from-date(current-date())-year-from-date(//Rate[.>=300]/preceding::dob[1]))
```

Output (licence number, name, age) :

```
'033329372|mike lornco|60'
```

To test : https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

I suppose you have multiple items. You can iterate with :

```
concat(normalize-space((//Rate[.>=300]/preceding::licenseNumber[1])[x]),"|",(//Rate[.>=300]/preceding::name[1])[x],"|",2020-number(substring((//Rate[.>=300]/preceding::dob[x])[1],1,4)))
```

Where [x] starts from 1 to XXX.

EDIT : Your XML data contains errors. This is what I've used :

```
<data>
<rent number="101111">
    <car>
        <startDate>2018-02-08</startDate>
        <endDate>2018-03-05</endDate>
        <Location>Toranto</Location>
        <carType>BMW</carType>
        <transmissionType>Automatic</transmissionType>
    </car>
    <person>
        <licenseNumber> 02389749372 </licenseNumber>
        <name>Alexa Steve</name>
        <dob>1999-03-01</dob>
        <phone>
            <type>Home</type>
            <number>44 010 1111 4567</number>
        </phone>
        <email> Alexa@steve.ca</email>
    </person>
    <price>
        <Rate>100.50</Rate>
    </price>
</rent>
<rent number="103311">
    <car>
        <startDate>2018-07-01</startDate>
        <endDate>2018-09-05</endDate>
        <Location>ottawa</Location>
        <carType>audi 8</carType>
        <transmissionType>Automatic</transmissionType>
    </car>
    <person>
        <licenseNumber> 033329372 </licenseNumber>
        <name>mike lornco</name>
        <dob>1960-03-03</dob>
        <phone>
            <type>Home</type>
            <number>44 010 1111 3333</number>
        </phone>
        <email> mikelornokorenco@gmail.com</email>
    </person>
    <price>
        <Rate>300.50</Rate>
    </price>
</rent>
</data>
```

EDIT 2 : Explanation of the XPath 1.0 expression :

We use `concat` to join the result of multiple operations (each one seperated with a ",") :

`normalize-space(//Rate[.>=300]/preceding::licenseNumber[1])` : we get the licence number of a person who has a car rental which is >= 300 (XPath syntax).
We use normalize-space() to remove leading and closing whitespaces.

We put a "|" to separate the result from the next one.

`//Rate[.>=300]/preceding::name[1]` : we get the name of a person who has a car rental which is >= 300 (XPath syntax).

`2020-substring(//Rate[.>=300]/preceding::dob[1],1,4)` : we get the birthdate of a person who has a car rental which is >= 300. With this birthdate, we extract with susbtring() the year of birth ("1,4" means we want values from character 1 to character 4). Finally we substract this value from 2020 to get the age of the person.

EDIT 3 : XPath 1.0 to get the longest booking, see [How do we get the Longest Booking in XPATH 1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61255658/how-do-we-get-the-longest-booking-in-xpath-1-0/61257337#61257337)

Comment: hi thank you can you please your query and what it does?

Comment: also the query : concat(normalize-space((//Rate[.>=300]/preceding::licenseNumber[1])[x]),"|",(//Rate[.>=300]/preceding::name[1])[x],"|",2020-number(substring((//Rate[.>=300]/preceding::dob[x])[1],1,4)))
its shows Nan . am using verision 1.0

Comment: I have a lot of data 11 in total which query checks it all?  the one which says multiple items throws a Nan

Comment: The query with [x] has to be used within a piece of code where [x] is the value you have to increment (in a loop for example). [x] starts from 1 to Z ( where Z is the number of nodes which respect your predicate Rate >=300). If your desired result is a list of formatted strings containing licence number|name|age, you can't do it in one single query with XPath 1.0. But you can use the XPath 1.0 expression for multiple items with a loop (code written in the language you want).

Comment: have one last question how can I get the  name of the person who got the longest booking  just by using the attribute StartDate and EndDate?

Comment: I cant add up a new question but really I appreciate your help ... what I tried is this: /rent/StartDate[not(text() <= preceding-sibling::StartDate/text()) and not(text() <=following-sibling::StartDate/text())].  my goal is to get the name of the person who booked the longest Booking .... Thank you!!

Comment: Post has been edited with an XPath 1.0  expression which should scope the longest booking.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for, where you can get the age based on the DOB in the xml.

```
xs:integer((current-date()-xs:date(//price[Rate >= 300]/parent::rent/person/dob/text())) div xs:dayTimeDuration('P365D'))
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: hey thank you but my version is "1.0" for XPath not sure why it's not working am getting an error says: xmlXPathCompOpEval: function current-date not found
XPath error : Unregistered function
XPath evaluation failure

Comment: can you also send the link of the tester u used?

Comment: I am using xpath 3.1 and you can find the method [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/) and here is the link for the [xpath tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're probably using XPath 1.0 (because people using later versions generally say so, and also because if you were using a later version, it would be easy).

> what I am trying to do is to get the driving licence and the names &
>   age of a person and the price of a car rental which is >= 300 alone [along?]
>   with the car type

One difficulty here is that XPath 1.0 isn't strong on returning a composite result like this. What do you actually want to return? A set of nodes (if so, which nodes?). Perhaps a formatted string containing the required information? If you want to construct a composite result as XML, then you're out of luck, because XPath 1.0 can't construct nodes, it can only select them.

The other difficulty is (as per your question) doing the join. XPath 1.0 is not "relationally complete" in Codd's terminology, that is, it doesn't have equivalent power to first-order predicate calculus, which means that not all joins are expressible.

My advice would therefore be that XPath 1.0 is the wrong tool for the job. You should be looking at XQuery, XPath 2.0, or XSLT. Do you have technology constraints that prevent you using such tools?

Comment: to return people names whos age less than or equal to 40 that's another option can that be achieved in version 1.0 xpath?

Comment: currently, I use visual studio editor, I want to update the version to XPath 2.0 but it says not supported how can I update editor to XPath 2.0

Comment: Switch to something like oXygen. People have been waiting for Microsoft to update their XML technology for 20 years. Alternatively look for third party VS plugins. Phil Fearon announced one the other day -- https://github.com/DeltaXML/vscode-xslt-tokenizer -- I haven't tried it.